# Webservice is not accessible publicly when using URL rewrite in IIS

Tags: web-services, http, url-rewriting, iis-8

I hosted webservice in private server. I then created URL rewrite rule in IIS which is there in public server(internet server).

Everytime I access the URL, It explicitly shows the private server's ip/ computer name in URL on browser rather than public url/IP. When I click on the URL for viewing script, it shows "Example.svc does not exist" error.

It also doesn't work when i try to add it as service reference in Visual studio by passing the URL in it. It throws the below error.

```
The request failed with HTTP status 400: Bad request
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: <SERVER URL>
The remote server turned an unexpected response: (405) Method not allowed.
```

What should I do for accessing the URL publicly and also able to add it as reference in Visual studio.?

Comment: That simply indicates you should set up a reverse proxy, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are deploying a WCF service in IIS. Is that correct? If the error `“example.svc does not exists”` occurred, please ensure that you have enabled certain Windows features in order to host WCF service in IIS.
[image]
The reason why we cannot add it as `Service Reference` in order to call the service is that we have not published the Metadata service endpoint. This depends on your WCF service type. Generally, we either add a Mex service endpoint or publish the service WSDL by adding Metadata service behavior.

```
  <services>
    <service name="WcfService1.Service1">
      <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="mybinding" contract="WcfService1.IService1">
      </endpoint>
      <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"></endpoint>
    </service>
  </services>
```

---

```
  <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
          <behavior>
            <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
```

> Everytime I access the URL, It explicitly shows the private server's ip/ computer name in URL on browser rather than public url/IP.

In order to access the service by using the hostname/domain name URL, we should ensure that the domain name points to the public IP of the server. It is a network-related issue. 
[image]

Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.